# Determine function parameters with neural network

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, control-theory

I am currently studying a doctoral thesis in control theory. At the end of every chapter there is a simulation of a relative-with-the-subject problem. I have finished the theory,but for further understanding I would like to reproduce the simulations. The first simulation is as follows :

The solution of the problem concludes in a system of differential equations whose right hand side consists of functions with unknown parameters. The author states the following : "We will use neural networks with one hidden layer,sigmoid basis functions and 5 weights in the external layer in order to approximate every parameter of the unknown functions.More specifically, the weights of the hidden layer are selected through iterative trials and are kept stable during the simulation." And then he states the logic with which he selects the initial values of the unknown parameters and then shows the results of the simulation.

Could anyone give me a lead on where to look and what I need to know in order to solve this specific problem myself in MATLAB (since this is the environment I am most familiar with)? Because the results of a google search are chaotic since I don't really know what I'm looking for.

If you need any more info,feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try MATLAB's [Neural Network Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/neural-network/). This gives you an nice UI where you can configure the network, train it with data to find the parameter values and test for performance. No coding involved.

Or, you can program it by hand. Since you are working with one hidden layer, it should be very simple. I am sure any machine learning or neural net (NN) textbook would have one example of it. You can also look into [GitHib](https://github.com/) for projects. There should be many NN projects there, in case you are looking to salvage code from existing project.

Most importantly, you should start by learning about NN, if you haven't done that already. NN with single hidden layer is easy to implement once you understand the equations for the forward and back propagation.